# Folder property/properties to set in VS solution to include it and files under it in build output

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

Wanted to include a folder and static files under it in a c# project to build output. The purpose is to use those static files in program by combining root location of assembly and the folder.

Comment: just drag and drop these folder/files into the solution it will be included in the output.

Comment: In the IDE, you can also click `Project - Add Existing Item`, or right click in the solution explorer tree and select `Add - Existing Item`.

Comment: @iSR5 :Appreciate your comments, but the folder and files are already part of the project. What i want is that, the files under that folder along with the folder should appear in the output folder as it is. Can you please suggest how i achieve that?

Comment: @MayurBhosale under your solution right click on these files, then properties, make sure their `Build Action` is `Content` and `Copy to Output Directory` is `always`.

Comment: @iSR5 Your suggestion helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Folder property/properties to set in VS solution to include it and
> files under it in build output

It is quite easy and you can directly drag the file or the entire folder to the project on the **solution explorer**.

**And** then change every file's **property** `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if Newer`.

**After that**, these static files will be under the build output folder.

This is a gif about the steps of the solution.

[image]